# How to run method in five seconds duration only

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have a method called in my android apps

```
updateArrayList(double data);
```

How to run the method in 5 seconds and stop after that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call the function 5 seconds from now, or do you want the function to run for at most 5 seconds (like if there was an infinite loop in there, it would break out after 5 seconds)?

Comment: Actually I want to do both. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You shuld try Thread.sleep(INT MILLIS); and in try catch block do operation

Answer (score 0):

use the timer class this is the full code

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class ReminderBeep {
  Toolkit toolkit;

  Timer timer;

  public ReminderBeep(int seconds) {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
  }

  class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Time's up!");
      toolkit.beep();
      //timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
      System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
    new ReminderBeep(5);
    System.out.println("Task scheduled.");
  }
}
```

this code from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    try { //you need the try and catch otherwise you get an error
        Thread.sleep(5000); //this is the actual waiting
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { //this can just be "Exception" it means that if the thread is told to start again, it wont cause an error.
        System.out.println("This code was told to start again.");
        //whatever you want to do if the code is told to start again during this.
    }
```